# Interpretation of post hoc for chi square test results in spss

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, post-hoc

working on 3 by 3 contingency table, the results of chi-square turned out significant, that was followed by computing adjusted residuals and calculating the p-value for each. only one cell returned as significant P. Any advice on how to interpret how the cell is different from the rest of cells ?

[image: 3 by 3 table]

Comment: Isn't this a 3 x 4? I see four categories on the left and three on the top if I'm not mistaken. Also...do you need p values for your individual factors?

Comment: Right, 3 by 4 , I have calculated the p value for each cell,, only the euthymia regular was significant (highlighted in yellow),,, I just don't know if tham means it is significantly different from all the cells or a certain categorie?